# Factoring fractions in sympy

Tags: math, sympy, algebra, fractions, factoring

How do I ask sympy to factor x**2  - 3/2*x + 1/2  into (x-1)*(x-1/2)?
The closest I've gotten is:

```
>>> (x**2  - Rational(3/2)*x + Rational(1/2)).factor()
(x - 1)*(2*x - 1)/2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way:

```
In [1]: expr = (x**2  - Rational(3/2)*x + Rational(1/2))

In [2]: expr
Out[2]: 
 2   3*x   1
x  - --- + -
      2    2

In [3]: fe = factor(expr)

In [4]: fe
Out[4]: 
(x - 1)*(2*x - 1)
-----------------
        2        

In [5]: fe.args
Out[5]: (1/2, x - 1, 2*x - 1)

In [6]: fe.args[0]*fe.args[2]*fe.args[1]
Out[6]: (x - 1)*(x - 1/2)
```

That is, you factor the expression *[3]*, then get the product arguments *[5]*, and multiply them *[6]*. The multiplication in step *[6]* calls some evaluation routines which slightly simplify the expression, but not to the point of expanding it.